# What's send json from unity3d

Tags: java, c#, json, unity-game-engine, netty

I decided to rewrite the game client with javascript on unity3d. Java socket server on netty.

I'm sending json using c# library socket.io.

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.AddField("q", "q");
Debug.Log(j.ToString());
socket.Emit(j.ToString());
```

`Debug.Log(j.ToString());`  shows `{"q":"q"}`, but the server messages always come with a 42 before the text  `42["{"q":"q"}"]`.

```
System.out.println(((TextWebSocketFrame) frame).text());
=> 42["{"q":"q"}"]
```

What is this 42? 42 is shown, regardless of what came json. 
 Json from javascript received correctly.

Comment: Could be the size of the data in bytes?

Comment: I do not think so `42["q",{"test1":"test1","test2":"test1","test3":"test1","test4":"test1","test5":"test1","test6":"test1","test7":"test1","test8":"test1","test9":"test1","test10":"test1","test11":"test1","test12":"test1"}]
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the first number indicates socket.io `EnginePacketType`, and the second`socketPacketType`.

```
EnginePacketType.MESSAGE = 4;
packet.socketPacketType(EVENT) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're sending data via socket.io and then trying to receive it via the netty.

Socket.io is not (purely) a library for opening a websocket connection and sending data through it, it has a protocol of messages and channels on top of the websocket layer.

Try making sure both sides use the same library.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that.